Include RicheText recursively in a table with python-docx-template
I just discovered the awesome python-docx-template. But I have trouble to include RichText recursively in a table.
Here is my template, the part that is the issue is circled in red :
When I render the doc, Word says that there is a problem. I guess this is because they are many "{{r" in the same context but I don't know how to write it well.
I tried doing a lot of research about richtext with python-docx-template but I didn't find the answer.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
